# First element sometimes not included in the second argument of Flux.switchOnFirst?

Tags: project-reactor

I'm trying to use the `SwitchOnFirst` operator from the reactor, which is amazing - except that sometimes the transformer passed as the second argument of the `BiFunction` doesn't seem to include the first element.
Basically, a client sends 2 items over `RSocket` to a server.
The code server side looks like this:

```
val socket = new AbstractRSocket() {

    override def requestChannel(payloads: Publisher[Payload]): Flux[Payload] =
      Flux.from(payloads).log.switchOnFirst((signal, all) => handle(signal.get(), all))

    private def handle(first: Payload, all: Flux[Payload]): Flux[Payload] =
      extractRoute(first) match {
        case Some("test.route") =>
          val source = Source.fromPublisher(all.log()).map(_.getDataUtf8)
          actorSink.runWith(source)
          return Flux.from(actorSource).map(DefaultPayload.create).runWith(Sink.asPublisher(false)))
      }

  }
```

The first time the client starts, the server receives both items and publishes them to the `actorsink` as expected.

```
[2020-02-01 16:17:42,656] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-2] - | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxDoFinally.DoFinallyFuseableSubscriber) {}
[2020-02-01 16:17:42,658] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-2] - | request(1) {}
[2020-02-01 16:17:42,664] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-2] - | onNext(io.rsocket.util.ByteBufPayload@53e655e6) {}
[2020-02-01 16:17:42,731] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.SwitchOnFirstInner.2] [] [akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] - onSubscribe(FluxSwitchOnFirst.SwitchOnFirstInner) {}
[2020-02-01 16:17:42,736] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.SwitchOnFirstInner.2] [] [akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] - request(16) {}
[2020-02-01 16:17:42,739] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.SwitchOnFirstInner.2] [] [akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] - onNext(io.rsocket.util.ByteBufPayload@53e655e6) {}
[2020-02-01 16:17:42,741] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1] [] [akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] - | request(15) {}
[Sink] Received (item1)
[2020-02-01 16:17:42,769] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-2] - | onNext(io.rsocket.util.ByteBufPayload@50215db3) {}
[2020-02-01 16:17:42,769] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.SwitchOnFirstInner.2] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-2] - onNext(io.rsocket.util.ByteBufPayload@50215db3) {}
[Sink] Received (item2)
[2020-02-01 16:17:42,770] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-2] - | onComplete() {}
[2020-02-01 16:17:42,771] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.SwitchOnFirstInner.2] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-2] - onComplete() {}
[Sink] Completed
```

However, if I stop the client and run it again, only the second item is published.

```
[2020-02-01 16:18:13,746] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.3] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-3] - | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxDoFinally.DoFinallyFuseableSubscriber) {}
[2020-02-01 16:18:13,746] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.3] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-3] - | request(1) {}
[2020-02-01 16:18:13,747] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.3] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-3] - | onNext(io.rsocket.util.ByteBufPayload@5a2d7823) {}
[2020-02-01 16:18:13,751] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.SwitchOnFirstInner.4] [] [akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] - onSubscribe(FluxSwitchOnFirst.SwitchOnFirstInner) {}
[2020-02-01 16:18:13,752] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.SwitchOnFirstInner.4] [] [akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] - request(16) {}
[2020-02-01 16:18:13,752] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.3] [] [akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] - | request(16) {}
[2020-02-01 16:18:13,787] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.3] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-3] - | onNext(io.rsocket.util.ByteBufPayload@1fa7bb46) {}
[2020-02-01 16:18:13,788] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.SwitchOnFirstInner.4] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-3] - onNext(io.rsocket.util.ByteBufPayload@1fa7bb46) {}
[Sink] Received (item2)
[2020-02-01 16:18:13,790] [INFO] [reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.3] [] [reactor-tcp-epoll-3] - | onComplete() {}
```

One difference is that `[SwitchOnFirstInner.4]` request(16) triggers a `[DoFinallyFuseable.3]` request(16), instead of `onNext` using the first item already available in the `SwitchOnFirst` operator.

I'm probably doing something wrong, but can't figure out what. The javadoc for `switchOnFirst` states that a publisher derived from the original Flux should be returned in all cases, which is not the case here (the input is sent to an ActorSink, and the output comes from a separate ActorSource), could it be the issue?

I'm new to reactor / rsocket so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: maybe try to remove the switching at first, to only see how the interaction between `Flux`, `Sink` and `Source` play out. I'm also suspiscious of your last line of code which appears to use `runWith` (an Akka Streams operator) directly on a `Flux`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not deriving the return Flux from the `all` Flux might indeed be the cause, especially if the `actorSink.runWith(source)` requests that `all` source, because the `switchOnFirst` operator is supposed to take care of the request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and for confirming that was the cause. It looks like there was a race condition in `SwitchOnFirst.onNext` between the call to BiFunction.apply and the method setting its `first` property. If the latter happened first, it worked, otherwise, first item was missing. Anyway, returning `Flux.defer( () => Flux.from(actorSource)... )` solved the issue. It kind of makes sense from my understanding of how `SwitchOnFirst works`, although maybe that's not how it was designed to be used ;)